# The Gamma function: does $0\cdot\infty=0$?

Tags: self-learning, gamma-distribution

My course notes (Mathematics BSc, second year Statistics module, unpublished) have

> For $n=1,2,\dots$, we have $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$

> *Proof.* Note that $$\Gamma(1)=\int_0^\infty e^{-u}=[-e^{-u}]_0^\infty=1.$$

> Using integration by parts, for any $\alpha>1$,
> \begin{align*}
> \int_0^\infty u^{\alpha-1}e^{-u} \text{d}u
> & = \left[u^{\alpha-1}(-e^{-u})\right]_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty(\alpha-1)u^{\alpha-2}(-e^{-u}) \text{d}u \\
> & = 0 + (\alpha-1)\int_0^\infty u^{\alpha-2}e^{-u} \text{d}u
> \end{align*}

> That is, $\Gamma(\alpha)=(\alpha-1)\Gamma(\alpha-1)$. By repeatedly applying this formula, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)(n-2)\dots(3)(2)\Gamma(1)$, and since $\Gamma(1)=1$ this gives $\Gamma(n)=n!$.

My question is: how come $\left[u^{\alpha-1}(-e^{-u})\right]_0^\infty=0$? I get
\begin{align*}
\left[u^{\alpha-1}(-e^{-u})\right]_0^\infty
& = \left[\infty^{\alpha-1}(-e^{-\infty})\right] - \left[0^{\alpha-1}(-e^{-0})\right] \\
& = \infty \cdot 0 - 0 \cdot 0 \\
& = \text{undefined} - 0 \\
& = \text{undefined}.
\end{align*}

What have I missed?

Comment: The evaluations of these "improper" integrals are defined in terms of *limits.*  Your use of the symbol "$\infty$"  as if it were a real number is incorrect.

Comment: @whuber Do you know where I can find a proof in terms of limits?

Comment: Refer to any Calculus text that covers Riemann integration.

Comment: @whuber OK, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this question was migrated, I will try to answer it in a fundamental way. OP asks why

$$\left[u^{\alpha-1}(-e^{-u})\right]_0^\infty=0$$

Hiding in this question though is an even more basic question: what do we mean by

$$\int_{0}^\infty f(x)dx$$

If you know anything about Riemann integration (which I believe you may not just based on your question) then this is a non-sensical thing to ask as Riemann integrals are defined over intervals; that is

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx$$

To extend this to limits of integration at infinity, we define

$$\int_{0}^\infty f(x)dx:=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_0^a f(x)dx$$

Then your original question becomes: what is

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[u^{\alpha-1}(-e^{-u})\right]_0^x$$

This we can do:

$$\left[u^{\alpha-1}(-e^{-u})\right]_0^x=x^{\alpha-1}(-e^{-x})-0^{\alpha-1}(-e^{-0})=-x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}$$

This implies

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[u^{\alpha-1}(-e^{-u})\right]_0^x=-\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}$$

Let $N$ be the smallest integer greater than $\alpha$. Then for $x>0$ we have

$$x^{1-\alpha}e^x=x^{1-\alpha}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}>x^{1-\alpha}\frac{x^N}{N!}=\frac{x^{N+1-\alpha}}{N!}$$

By definition, we have $N+1-\alpha>\alpha+1-\alpha=1$. Thus, the expression is greater than $\frac{x}{N!}$. This implies

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}x^{1-\alpha}e^x\geq \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{N!}=\infty$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}=0$$